# Why can't I write a sitemap to a temporary directory on a Heroku stack that has a read-only file system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake, sitemap

I'm generating a sitemap for my website and temporarily saving it to the tmp folder to be then uploaded to my Amazon AWS account. I'm using the sitemap generator and fog gems to help me. So far I have this...

```
# In sitemap.rb

# Set the host name for URL creation
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = "http://mycoolapp.com/"

# pick a place safe to write the files
#SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.public_path = 'tmp/'

# store on S3 using Fog
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.adapter = SitemapGenerator::S3Adapter.new

# inform the map cross-linking where to find the other maps
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_host = "http://#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com/"

# pick a namespace within your bucket to organize your maps
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_path = '/'

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do
  # Put links creation logic here.
  #

  add '/home'

  add '/about'

  add '/contact'
end
```

Whenever I run `heroku run rake sitemap:create` I receive the following error...

```
In '/app/tmp/':
511
rake aborted!
Read-only file system - /sitemap.xml.gz
```

I'm really at a loss as to why it's not working. I even went as far as making sure the tmp folder is created by running `Rails.root.join('tmp')` as an initializer. Any help in solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, heroku does not allow you to modify the filesystem directly - you must build your sitemaps in-memory and stream them to aws without using a temp file.

Comment: Hmm any link to help me go on my way?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem

Comment: I've read this before and it didn't help me much. If anything it tells me that my code should work because I'm writing it to the tmp, `There are two directories that are writeable: ./tmp and ./log`. What am I getting confused on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Don't Write to Root of Filesystem

Rake is quite clear about the source of the error:

> rake aborted!
>   Read-only file system - /sitemap.xml.gz

This is telling you that your rake task is attempting to write the file to the root of the filesystem.

If you aren't using a a stack with [ephemeral filesystem support](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) like [Celadon Cedar](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar), you need to ensure you're writing to `#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp` rather than the root of the filesystem. I haven't tested this myself, but you may be able to fixing this issue simply by pointing `sitemaps_path` to a [writable directory](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem). For example:

```
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_path = '/app/tmp'
```

If that doesn't work, you'll have to track down where your gem or rake task is defining the root directory as the location for writing the `sitemap.xml.gz` file.

Comment: Hmm I thought sitemaps_path was meant for AWS path location?

Comment: @jason328 It's actually the "bucket namespace." If changing that value doesn't help, you might also try setting `SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.public_path = 'tmp/'` as used in the [example on the wiki](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator/wiki/Generate-Sitemaps-on-read-only-filesystems-like-Heroku). You currently have that line commented out. If that works, I'll update the answer; if not, you'll have to follow the rest of my advice and track down where the write path is being defined.

Comment: Yeah, it didn't work for me. I guess I'll have to track down the write path.

Comment: Although I still don't know how to solve this problem besides looking for the write path (not sure where to start with that), I'll give you credit for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

So, I encountered the same problem trying to follow the `fog` instructions on both Heroku and for the `sitemap_generator` gem.  I eventually switched to `carrierwave` and found it to be plug and play.

Check out the documentation [here](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator/wiki/Generate-Sitemaps-on-read-only-filesystems-like-Heroku) and let me know if you have questions as I just did this a couple months ago and likely have encountered any hurdles you may run in to.

Comment: I ended up trying carrierwave and it didn't work in the end. I received the same error as posted in the question.

Comment: Sounds like your app wasn't configured to have the sitemap_generator send to S3

Comment: I'm not sure how to approach the problem then. I followed the instructions to the dot.

Comment: Let me know if you want to jump on an SO chat and we can troubleshoot.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41220/discussion-between-cdub-and-jason328)